# Xamarin.Forms ListView Deletion of Items holds old values

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView and populate it via DataBinding to a Lists Property in my ViewModel. Additionally, I have a menu for the ListView, with a Delete Command, also bound to my ViewModel.
My Problem is now, if I have the ListView initialized, I can delete the lists in it. If I add new lists, I can delete all lists. But then, if I add new items, I can't delete them, because the List I get from the DeleteCommand is the old, already deleted list.

So, after deleting lists, they seem to be somehow, somewhere still present and I can only delete new lists, if the total amount of current lists is higher, than any previous amount of deleted lists.

I hope this is a somehow understandable explanation of my problem.

The Binding is working and Lists Property in my ViewModel holds the correct values, but the "sender" ItemList in the DeleteListCommand is the old ItemList.

Here is my XAML for my ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell x:Name="viewCell">
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding BindingContext.RenameListCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Rename" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteListCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsDestructive="True" Text="Delete" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <ContentView Margin="0,2,0,2"
                                    HeightRequest="50"
                                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">

                    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                                        Command="{Binding ListTappedCommand}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference viewCell}, Path=BindingContext}" />
                    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <ContentView.Content>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    TextColor="White" 
                                    IsEnabled="True"/>
                    </ContentView.Content>

                </ContentView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And here is  my ViewModel:

```
...
public ObservableCollection<ItemList> lists = new ObservableCollection<ItemList>();
        public ObservableCollection<ItemList> Lists
        {
            get { return lists; }
            set
            {
                lists = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Lists");
            }
        }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

...

this.DeleteListCommand = new Command<ItemList>((sender) =>
            {
                    OnDeleteList(sender);
            });

...

public ICommand DeleteListCommand { get; set; }
private void OnDeleteList(ItemList itemList)
        {
            Lists.Remove(itemList);
        }

...

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: What is "ItemList"? is it observable too?

Comment: It is just a normal class, used as a model for my DataBase for sqlite-net-pcl with string and bool properties. I also use this class for the ObservableCollection so that I don't have to cast to different types. How should I make it observable?

Comment: so, it is not a list? I understood you are using nested lists. is that correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the unclarity. ItemList is just a class and no list, I call it ItemList, because I store ItemIds in a string property in it. So no, it is not nested.

Comment: Then what you are describing shouldn't happen. Can you share sample project and describe steps to reproduce the problem and expected result?

Comment: Here is a sampl:
https://github.com/mKay00/Test
Just click on the add button on the lower left corner and right click on the list and delete it. Make this step another time and it should result in the list not deleting.

Comment: Right click? Are you working on UWP?

Comment: Yes, right click and yes UWP.

Comment: it works in iOS, something wrong with UWP. Probably workaround is available but do you want to create a bug in bugzilla?

Comment: I think this will answer your question. Unfortunately I cannot post it as an answer because I cannot take credit for that https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86578/couple-of-problems-with-listview-context-actions-uwp

Comment: tested their solution. It works!

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I am still learning about data binding and can't get it working, because when I use a new BindingContext, I lose my binding to my ViewModel and can't call the command anymore. Since it works for you, would you be so kind to share your solution?

Comment: And the bug is already reported on bugzilla with the id 42516:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42516

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on sample project here is what you need to do: Name you cell "viewCell" because you need to pass cell to your model to be able to reset ContextAction.
Change binding on menu item to pass the cell instead of ItemList. Then in model reset context action and get an item from binding context of the cell

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TobyList_XamarinForms"
                 xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:TobyList_XamarinForms.ViewModels"
                 Title="Toby" 
             x:Class="TobyList_XamarinForms.Views.MasterPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#F9F9F9">

        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <localVM:MasterPageViewModel />
        </StackLayout.BindingContext>


        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell x:Name="viewCell">
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteListCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference viewCell}}" Text="Delete" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <ContentView Margin="0,2,0,2"
                                        HeightRequest="50"
                                        BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">

                        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                                            Command="{Binding ListTappedCommand}" 
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference viewCell}, Path=BindingContext}" />
                        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <ContentView.Content>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        TextColor="White"/>
                        </ContentView.Content>

                    </ContentView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="30" Margin="7">
            <Label Text="Add">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AddListCommand}" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TobyList_XamarinForms.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace TobyList_XamarinForms.ViewModels
{
    public class MasterPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemList> lists = new ObservableCollection<ItemList>();
        public ObservableCollection<ItemList> Lists
        {
            get { return lists; }
            set
            {
                lists = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Lists");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MasterPageViewModel()
        {
            this.AddListCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                OnAddList();
            });
            //this.DeleteListCommand = new Command<ItemList>((sender) =>
            //{
            //  OnDeleteList(sender);
            //});

            this.DeleteListCommand = new Command<ViewCell>((sender) =>
            {
                OnDeleteList(sender);
            });

        }

        public ICommand AddListCommand { get; protected set; }
        private void OnAddList()
        {
            ItemList itemList = new ItemList() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper(), Name = "Lorem Ipsum", Color = "#000000" };
            Lists.Add(itemList);
        }

        public ICommand DeleteListCommand { get; set; }
        //public void OnDeleteList(ItemList itemList)
        //      {
        //          Lists.Remove(itemList);
        //      }
        public void OnDeleteList(ViewCell viewCell)
        {
            viewCell.ContextActions.Clear();
            Lists.Remove((ItemList)viewCell.BindingContext);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```